# How to change UnitPrice via Dynamics GP API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp, dynamics-gp-api

I would like to change UnitPrice when create an order via Dynamics GP API,

So I run next code:

```
// Create a sales order object
        var salesOrder = new SalesOrder();

        // Create a sales document type key for the sales order
        var salesOrderType = new SalesDocumentTypeKey();
        salesOrderType.Type = SalesDocumentType.Order;

        // Populate the document type key of the sales order object
        salesOrder.DocumentTypeKey = salesOrderType;

        // Create a customer key
        var customerKey = new CustomerKey();
        customerKey.Id = customerSummary[0].Key.Id;

        // Set the customer key property of the sales order object
        salesOrder.CustomerKey = customerKey;

        // Create a batch key
        var batchKey = new BatchKey();
        batchKey.Id = "01-INBOUND";

        // Set the batch key property of the sales order object
        salesOrder.BatchKey = batchKey;

        // Create a sales order line to specify the ordered item
        var salesOrderLine = new SalesOrderLine();

        // Create an item key
        var orderedItem = new ItemKey();
        orderedItem.Id = "AA1111";

        // Set the item key property of the sales order line object
        salesOrderLine.ItemKey = orderedItem;

        // Create a sales order quantity object
        var orderedAmount = new Quantity();
        orderedAmount.Value = 1;

        // Set the quantity of the sales order line object
        salesOrderLine.Quantity = orderedAmount;


        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
        salesOrderLine.UnitPrice = new MoneyAmount { Value = 1.11m, Currency = "USD"  };

        // Discount works ok
        // salesOrderLine.Discount = new MoneyPercentChoice { Item = new MoneyAmount { Value = 1.25m } };

        // Create an array of sales order lines
        // Initialize the array with sales order line object
        SalesOrderLine[] orders = { salesOrderLine };

        // Add the sales order line array to the sales order
        salesOrder.Lines = orders;

        // Get the create policy for the sales order object
        var salesOrderCreatePolicy = dynamicsGP.GetPolicyByOperation("CreateSalesOrder", context);

        // Create the sales order
        dynamicsGP.CreateSalesOrder(salesOrder, context, salesOrderCreatePolicy);
```

But line to change UnitPrice doesn't work.

```
        salesOrderLine.UnitPrice = new MoneyAmount { Value = 1.11m, Currency = "USD"  };
```

What I'm doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

> In Dynamics GP Web Service Policy Configuration for Update Sales
>   Invoice Policy, you need to update the “Calculate Unit Price Behavior”
>   to “Do Not Calculate”.
>
> Also, make Sure that you have selected the right Company and assigned
>   proper roles for the policy. The role should not be Default.

Source: https://www.cloudfronts.com/dynamics-gp-sales-invoice-unit-price-always-0/